# SwiftUI How to use View Model with nested JSON

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm learning iOS development and I'm trying to modify my app to use MVVM model. Below I'm pasting json structure that I'm using. I'm able to access categories, but I encountered an issue when I tried to iterate through Items. How my view model should look like? Do I need 2 view models one for Category and another one for Item? Also how to combine View Model with AppStorage?

```
[
    {
        "id": "8DC6D7CB-C8E6-4654-BAFE-E89ED7B0AF94",
        "name": "Category",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": "59B88932-EBDD-4CFE-AE8B-D47358856B93",
                "name": "Item1",
                "isOn": false
            },
            {
                "id": "E124AA01-B66F-42D0-B09C-B248624AD228",
                "name": "Item2",
                "isOn": false
            }
     }
 ]
```

View

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MyModel()
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.items, id: \.self) { id in
                Text(id.name)
                //how to iterate through items?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var items: [ItemsSection] = [ItemsSection]()

    init(){
        loadData()
    }

    func loadData()  {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "items", withExtension: "json")
        else {
            print("Json file not found")
            return
        }
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
        let items = try? JSONDecoder().decode([ItemsSection].self, from: data!)
        self.items = items!
    }
    
    
    func getSelectedItemsCount() -> Int{
        var i: Int = 0
        for itemSection in items {
            let filteredItems = itemSection.items.filter { item in
                return item.isOn
            }
            i = i + filteredItems.count
        }
        return i
    }
}
```

Model:

```
struct ItemSection: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable  {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var items: [Item]
}

struct Item: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable,Hashable  {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var isOn: Bool = false
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The problem will be in your `codable`, `ItemsSection`, that you have not shown.

Comment: @Yrb I added model

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions simultaneously. This can lead for your question to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over the your `items` array you can do something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // This should be @StateObject as this View owns the viewmodel
    @StateObject var viewModel = MyModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            //ItemSection is Identifiable so no need for `id: \.self` here.
            ForEach(viewModel.sections) { section in
            //Section is a View provided by Apple that can help you laying
            // out your View. You don´t have to, you can use your own
                Section(section.name){
                    ForEach(section.items){ item in
                        Text(item.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I´ve changed the naming in thew Viewmodel as I think the naming of `items` var should really be `sections`.

```
class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var sections: [ItemsSection] = [ItemsSection]()
    
    init(){
        loadData()
    }
    
    func loadData()  {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "items", withExtension: "json")
        else {
            print("Json file not found")
            return
        }
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let sections = try JSONDecoder().decode([ItemsSection].self, from: data)
            
            self.sections = sections
        } catch {
            print("failed loading or decoding with error: ", error)
        }
    }
    
    func getSelectedItemsCount() -> Int{
        var i: Int = 0
        for itemSection in sections {
            let filteredItems = itemSection.items.filter { item in
                return item.isOn
            }
            i = i + filteredItems.count
        }
        return i
    }
}
```

And never use `try?` use a proper `do / catch` block and print the error. This will help you in future to identify problems better. For example the example JSON you provided is malformatted. Without proper `do / catch` it will just crash while force unwrap.

Comment: hello burnsi, do you know how to add to this class user defaults so I can just clear all the selections using one button?

Comment: @paulatraveler The way SO works is one question at a time. If you have another question please open a new one. You can mark me here with `@burnsi` and I will give it a try. If this answer answered your question please consider marking it as the accepted answer with the green checkmark.

Comment: will do. sorry. not sure how to mark you. I'll try. thanks for all the replies.